# Authorization HTTP header with ASP.NET

Tags: php, asp.net, .net, curl

I want to create an authorization http header using asp.net i have the code given in documentation if i want to do it using php+ curl here is the link http://help.voxeo.com/go/help/evolution.sms.postapi .

I dont want to install php on my IIS and want to work purely in .net environment . Can some one give asp alternative to following code :

```
$botkey='[999999]';

$from="14075551212";

$userKey = $_REQUEST['userkey'];

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.messaging.staging.voxeo.net/1.0/messaging');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$data="botkey=".$botkey."&apimethod=send&msg=".$msg."&userkey=".$userKey."&network=SMS&   from=".$from;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, '[Evolution User Name]:[Evolution Password]');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

c    url_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
```

I need ASP.net alternative to below curl

```
curl -u MyUserName:MyPassword "http://api.messaging.staging.voxeo.net/1.0/messaging" -X POST -d "botkey=12345&apimethod=send&msg=My%20test%20message.&user=14075555555&network=SMS&from=14076666666"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you completely but this is something I had to do to allow flash to get to a secure section of my app. I have more checks in place which I have removed for sake of clarity but this will create an authorisation cookie if this is what you need. I must ask though, why can't you use the normal authentication methods in ASP.NET?

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string SessionParamName = "";
    string SessionCookieName = "";
    string AuthParamName = "";
    string AuthCookieName = "";

    try
    {
        SessionParamName = "ASPSESSID";
        SessionCookieName = "ASP.NET_SessionId";
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[SessionParamName] != null)
            UpdateCookie(SessionCookieName, HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[SessionParamName]);
        else if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[SessionParamName] != null)
            UpdateCookie(SessionCookieName, HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[SessionParamName]);
    }
    catch { }

    try
    {
        AuthParamName = "AUTHID";
        AuthCookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[AuthParamName] != null)
            UpdateCookie(AuthCookieName, HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[AuthParamName]);
        else if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[AuthParamName] != null)
            UpdateCookie(AuthCookieName, HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[AuthParamName]);
    }
    catch { }
}

private void UpdateCookie(string CookieName, string CookieValue)
{
    HttpCookie Cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get(CookieName);
    if (Cookie == null)
        Cookie = new HttpCookie(CookieName);

    Cookie.Value = CookieValue;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(Cookie);
}
```

Comment: I have no idea if i can use asp.net's normal authentication methods or not as the tutorial does not mention it . Would I be able to set the headers using normal authentication methods.

Comment: I think most servers do not accept direct authorization and require setting up a header or cookie

Comment: http://help.voxeo.com/go/help/evolution.sms.postapi    this website has it written under authentication heading . This is what i am trying to achieve actually

Comment: Are you trying to authenticate yourself on "their" application?